# Python textwrap and ignoring parts of string

Tags: python, string, word-wrap

Totally beginner coder here, first-posting in this fine place. Using Python 3.2.3.

**Quick description**

I want to wordwrap and char-fill strings, but some parts of the string should be ignored.

**Background**

I'm working with a program that outputs text from .txt files, but doesn't have wordwrap or   line breaks. Since I can't edit the program's functionality at least for now, my only option is to edit the text files.

The program uses a fixed-size monospace font, so I know the specific character count for each file & line. I'm using the program's hard-space command \_ as a fill character for each wrapped row (except last). The hard-space command is temporarily converted to **#** to keep correct character counts in my script.

Here's a rather altered and simplified version of my text-edit script:

```
from textwrap import TextWrapper

linelist = ['"I thought that...\p glob was a weird\_name for a module."',
"Nobody can tell a secret from the \p\shake{1}sky unless they borrow wings \
from their neighbors. It's a pity, really. Life on the ground can be a bore.",
'\shake{6} The ground was trembling. What\wait{150} \pcould\wait{1300} the \
townfolk do? Even the pizzeria was closed.']

ww = TextWrapper(break_on_hyphens="False", width=30)

def space_wordwrap(wwl):
    out = []
    for ln in ww.wrap(wwl):
        out.append("{0:#<{1:d}}".format(ln, ww.width))
        #just a quick workaround for simpler print output for SO question
        if not ln in ww.wrap(wwl)[-1]:
            out[-1] += "\n"
    return ''.join(out).rstrip('#')

for line in linelist:
    #line = line.replace('\\_', '#')
    if len(line) > ww.width:
        line = space_wordwrap(line)
    #line = line.replace('#', '\\_')
    print(line + "\n")
```

**The problem**

Many lines in the text files have the program's commands in them. These commands aren't displayed as text by the program, but their positioning is important... and they are placed anywhere around the displayable text. This throws off the character count of the wordwrap.

There are 4 commands: `\p \wait{100} \stop{200} \shake{1}`. See `linelist` for examples.

The output of the script is this:

```
"I thought that...\p glob was#
a weird\_name for a module."

Nobody can tell a secret from#
the \p\shake{1}sky unless they
borrow wings from their#######
neighbors. It's a pity,#######
really. Life on the ground can
be a bore.

\shake{6} The ground was######
trembling. What\wait{150}#####
\pcould\wait{1300} the########
townfolk do? Even the pizzeria
was closed.
```

I think I have to remove the program commands from the line and then insert them back in their respective locations after wordwrapping, but I'm not sure what would be the cleanest way to go about it.

My initial thought was to find the previous word (if any) and use that as reference. I'd have checked if there's a \ used, find a space before it that isn't followed by a \, store that previous word in a list and then insert an order number on the word in case there are many similar words on the line.

Whew! That turned out to be a pretty lengthy description. Any suggestions on how it should be done? Also, if any of my coding practices seem silly, I'd be glad to know. Still just getting started, after all. :-]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this but...

Pre-process the text, removing the commands and remembering where they were, as a character offset from the beginning of the text.

Then do your word-wrapping.

Finally re-insert the commands. You might need to step through the final text character by character, so that you can ignore # characters and /n and /r when calculating the command character positions.

An approximate solution, which might be good enough, would be to replace the commands with place-holder characters that you know won't appear in the source text, such as @, ~, &, etc while the reformatting is done, then put the commands back in afterwards. The output will not be perfectly wrapped as some lines may have more spaces at the end than necessary.

Comment: Pre-process and re-insert it is. Thought as much, just with a clumsier method. Muchas gracias!